# How to fix akka version compatibility issues?

Tags: scala, redis, apache-spark

I was thinking of using spark and redis together with SBT.

It runs fine if I comment out the spark dependency, if I include the spark dependency I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.actor.ActorSystem.dispatcher()Lscala/concurrent/ExecutionContextExecutor;
    at redis.RedisClientActorLike.<init>(Redis.scala:31)
    at redis.RedisClient.<init>(Redis.scala:69)
```

I have no issues when I do not include "redisscala". When I do include redisscala, then I get weird errors about Akka.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that those versions of Spark and rediscala are using incompatible versions of Akka. Spark 1.1.0 is using Akka 2.2.3, and rediscala 1.3.1 is using Akka 2.3.4. There are some  changes between Akka 2.2.x and 2.3.x that are causing issues, and your project currently has both as transient dependencies.

You either need to downgrade rediscala to 1.2 (which uses Akka 2.2.x), or upgrade Spark to 1.2-snapshot (which uses Akka 2.3.x).

Comment: Is it a one line change to build.sbt to use the 1.2-snapshot? If so, could you show me what the build.sbt would look like (for the dependencies or any new resolvers to get to the snapshot)

Comment: I'm not sure that 1.2-snapshot is published anywhere, so you might have to build and publish it locally. It might be better to just downgrade rediscala, and keep the stable versions. In which case, just use `"com.etaty.rediscala" %% "rediscala" % "1.2"` instead